# What is the correct way to obtain EntityManager using JNDI?

Tags: ejb-3.0

Am a novice in ejb trying to learn the topic..and came across this question in one of certification questions..

The options are

```
             EntityManager em=(EntityManager)context.lookup("Persistance")
             EntityManager em=(EntityManager)context.lookup()
             EntityManager em=context.lookup()
             EntityManager em=context.lookup("persistance")
```

Please explain the reason of the answer too.Would like to learn.

Answer (score 1):

In your new list all options are still wrong.

- 1 and 2 are wrong, because dot before opening bracket is incorrect syntax.
- 3 and 4 are wrong, because cast of the result is missing.
- 2 and 3 are wrong, because argument to lookup method is missing.

First one is still closest match. Removing dot before opening bracket and assuming PersistenceManager for name "Persistence" exists in JNDI, it would work.

As and addition second ant third are incorrect because they miss argument for lookup. Fourth one is incorrect, because it does not cast result of lookup. So, first one is less bad than three other candidates.

If needed resources are available, I suggest to learn more with actually compiling and running code. And get good book about subject or check more for example from tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/

Comment: Thank you Mikko.., it was my typo in writing EntityManager wrongly and also about the "." just after lookup.. I have corrected the question

Comment: Thank you mikko. The dot before opening is not part of the options.again my typo.sorry for that.remaining very well s the question. want to check if PersistanceManager exists for "persistence" in  JNDI. It might very well answer tht... thanks a lot